# Configuring Intellij IDEA to work with Smartsheet-api sdk for java

Tags: intellij-idea, smartsheet-api

I am setting up smartsheet SDK for Java, and running into problems trying to use it in IntelliJ IDEA. I am fairly unfamiliar with setting up decencies, modules, and such in IntelliJ, and am just looking for guidance on setting this up to work with Smartsheet SDK.

I'm currently using the Windows version with JDK13 (I also have JDk12). I've tried downloading the JAR file and pointing to that as a dependency, but it doesn't even understand the imports.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the Smartsheet Sample App for Java, which will already have the code in it for loading dependencies and libraries. https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/java-read-write-sheet